# Using soft delete in laravel 5 issue

Tags: php, laravel, traits, soft-delete

This is my model:

```
namespace App\Models\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Image extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    //table
    protected $table = 'images';
}
```

If I add my trait I cannot find any record if I use my model like this:

```
$imageFile = ImageModel::where('id', 12)->first();
```

The `$imageFile` is always `null`, if I remove my trait is working . Why ???

Comment: Is Image #12 deleted? If so, you should be using `Image::withTrashed()->where('id', 12')->first();`.

Comment: To it is not .  As I said If I remove this part `use SoftDeletes;` from my mode is working .I am getting data from `ImageModel::where('id', 12)->first();`. IF I keep , it is null.

Comment: Deleted with soft deletes means `deleted_at` field is not null.

Comment: All i want to do is to delete and item , do some stuff . If those stuff fails for some reason, then roll back my item

Comment: Using this `ImageModel::destroy($id)` I believed it will remove my item, but it only updates the `deleted_at` column from null to current date then I want to do my stuff , If those stuff fails I would like to call a function where I want to roll back my 'delete move'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said, it is working as intended.  When you use the soft-delete trait in Laravel, the model is NOT deleted from the DB.  When you pass the model to destroy(), the only thing that happens is that the deleted_at field becomes non-null.

If you look deeper into Laravel's code, when you call

```
ImageModel::where('id', 12)->first();
```

the softdelete trait is adding

```
where null
```

to the SQL for the deleted_at column.  This means that, as you said, if you turn off the trait, $imageFile will not be null (it is working).  Because the softdelete never deleted the model from the DB - it just added a non-null value to the DB for that model and is thus visible to a normal laravel query: when you don't use softdeletes, Laravel doesn't care about the deleted_at field so it sees the model.  When you turn softdeletes on, it looks for null values only, and because your model was softdeleted (it has a non-null value), it returns $imageFile as null.

As bytewave said, to properly use the softdeletes to NOT return a null value to $imageFile, you would need to add in the softdeleted models to your query like so:

```
Image::withTrashed()->where('id', 12')->first();
```

I think you were looking for slightly different functionality (a roll-back), which is a little different from the softdelete trait's intention.  The manual is pretty good: [5.4 soft-deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#soft-deleting), but looking deeper into the trait code might help as well.

Take a look at the ->restore() function as well - this might help you get closer to the intended roll-back you were looking for.  But, you need the logic up-front first to know which were deleted.